# Cannot locate chrome policies.json on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, ubuntu-18.04

Hi i'm trying to access chrome policies.json file for adding a site to whitelist without using gui. But "/etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed" directory is missing. Should i create this directories and write sample json ? Any help would be appreciated.